# Different behaviour of netbeans and console

Tags: java, console, netbeans-7

I have written a code in java. In which I have created a package called `xml-creator`.
Package `xml_creator` has 3 classes say `XML_Control`, `XML_Creator`, and `XML_implement`.

When I run my project on netbeans (**NetBeans 7.0**) it works fine. But if I try to compile code on console, I get various errors like

When I compiled `XML_Creator.java`, I get following errors.

```
XML_Creator.java:371: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable XML_implement
location: class xml_creator.XML_Creator
                    typeAttr.setValue(XML_implement.table_col[i][2]);
                                      ^
XML_Creator.java:375: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable XML_implement
location: class xml_creator.XML_Creator
                for(int j=0;j<XML_implement.kTab;j++)
                              ^
```

`XML_Creator` and `XML_implemenr` both are in same package but non of them extend each other.

I am sorry I cant show code on this site as it is too large and **aginst the company's policies**.

I dont understand why it is showing me errors?

Sample code
**XML_Control.java**

```
package xml_creator;
public class XML_Control 
{
    public static void main(String as[])
    {
        XML_Creator xml = new XML_Creator();    
    }
}
```

**XML_Creator.java**

```
package xml-creator;

public class XML_Creator
{
    XML_implement ixml = new XML_implement();
    public XML_Creator() 
    {
        System.out.println(""+ixml.a);
    }
}
```

**XML_implement.java**

```
package xml_creator;
public class XML_implement 
{
    public int a;
    public XML_implement()
    {
        a = 10;
    }
}
```

So when I compile `XML_Creator.java`, console gives error.

Comment: You haven't shown us how you're trying to compile your code - and even if you can't post the *real* code, you could post a short but complete program which demonstrates the problem. (You should also be aware that your class names don't follow Java naming conventions...)

Comment: I am compiling using javac.  i.e.  javac XML_Creator.java

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you're compiling *within the directory containing the .java file*, and only telling the compiler about one of the source files. That's the problem - to try to find a source or class file, the compiler is using the package name, and expecting the packages to be laid out in the conventional fashion. Compile from the root of the source tree - which I certainly *hope* you're using - like this:

```
javac xml_creator/*.java
```

You may also want to specify an output directory - which again will be the root of the directory hierarchy for packages:

```
javac -d bin xml_creator/*.java
```

If you're building *regularly* from the command-line (and not just for throwaway code) you should look into using a build system such as [Ant](http://ant.apache.org/).

Comment: I a sorry Jon, but I dont understand any thing. I am just a beginer and your explanation is highly proffessional. It may be correct, but I cant trace the solution you are giving me. Will you please explain it in simple language.

Comment: @SDM: This *is* pretty simple language. Which part of it don't you understand? You haven't told us anything about how your source is laid out, but I'd *expect* it to be in directories corresponding to your package names. So run the command as shown from the root of that package hierarchy. If you're new to Java but working as a developer in a company, you should probably ask your team members to be honest - they'll be able to show you directly, walking you through it.